# Display everything from specific value inside child - Xamarin Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, xaml, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following firebase database:

[image: database]

And let's say I want to display all the values inside "Rest1". How can I do it?

I currently use the following code to make the connection and display **everything** inside the database.

display.xaml.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord> DatabaseItems { get; set; } = new
      ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord>();

    FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("link");


    private void tabelaRestLoad()
    {
        var collection = firebaseClient
            .Child("Menus")
            .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
            .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
            {
                if (dbevent != null)
                {
                    DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
                }
            });
    }
```

display.xaml:

```
    <StackLayout Margin="15,0,15,5" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseItems}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged"  BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="#fff2d8" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10,0,5" Padding="2" WidthRequest="350" CornerRadius="10">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#fff2d8">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Plate1}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" FontSize="20"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Plate2}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" FontSize="17"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Plate3}" TextColor="Black" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="15"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MyDatabaseRecord.cs:

```
public class MyDatabaseRecord
{
    public string Plate1 { get; set; }
    public string Plate2 { get; set; }
    public string Plate3 { get; set; }
}
```

As I said, this code I'm using returns every "Plate" value from both Rest1 and Rest2 inside "Menus" child. My question here is, how can I only display the values inside Rest1, for example, instead of all of them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `DatabaseItems[0]` will return the first item in your list

Comment: @Jason but what If I want to return string based? For example return every data inside "Rest2" or "Rest1" instead of just going through positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal code change would be to [use a query](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet#querying) on the key:

```
var collection = firebaseClient
    .Child("Menus")
    .OrderByKey()
    .EqualTo("Rest1")
    .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
    ...
```